# Apply threshold to the elements of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

How can I quicky get an index vector showing if all elements of Matrix with correpsponding number of rows has all elemets in this row below some threshold?

for instance:

```
threshold = 5;

A = [5,6;4,5;3,4];
```

should give

```
[0;0;1];
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
threshold = 5;
A = [5,6;4,5;3,4];
all((A < 5)')
```